# more than 1 value in same attribute

Tags: c#, xml

Im new here and my english is not good! i hope you can understand what i mean!

main:

i have a program C# convert xml to xml but with difference structure!

this mine:

```
<require_skill>
    <skillIds>236</skillIds>
    <skillIds>237</skillIds>
    <skillIds>238</skillIds>
    <skillIds>239</skillIds>
    <skillIds>240</skillIds>
    <skillIds>2039</skillIds>
    <skillIds>2811</skillIds>
</require_skill>
```

and i want to make it like this

```
<require_skill skillIds="236 237 238 239 240 2039 2811"/>
```

this is my code:

```
[XmlElement("require_skill", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public RequireStigmaSkill[] require_skill;

[Serializable]
[XmlType(Namespace = "", AnonymousType = true)]
public class RequireStigmaSkill
{
    //[XmlAttribute]
    //public String skilllvl;

    [XmlElement("skillIds", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public String[] skillIds;
}
```

in main program:

```
utility.Export<String>(item, "require_skill", requiredGen);
if (requiredGen.Count() > 0)
{
    List<RequireStigmaSkill> requiredArray = new List<RequireStigmaSkill>();
    foreach (string asName in requiredGen)
    {
        //asName as SkillStartname
        List<String> forThisName = new List<string>();
        foreach (ClientSkill skillGen in skills.SkillList)
        {
            if (skillGen.name.StartsWith(asName))
            {
                if (skillGen.name.StartsWith(asName))
                    forThisName.Add(skillGen.id);
            }
        }

        //Did it.
        var required = new RequireStigmaSkill();
        //required.skilllvl = "1";
        required.skillIds = forThisName.ToArray();
        requiredArray.Add(required);
    }
    i.stigma.require_skill = requiredArray.ToArray();
}
```

How do I make more than 1 value in the same attribute?

Comment: What will "requiredGen", "skills", "item" variables contain and what is their type? Please update the question with this information.

Comment: List<String> requiredGen = new List<String>();

public static ClientSkillFile skills = null;

Answer (score 0):

I am actually not able to understand your main code so I tried to create a string as you want. Try and map it to your code and make the necessary changes if possible. The following are the steps I did:

1. Created a xml file and copy-pasted your input xml
2. Loaded the xml file and created the string. The following is the code for the same:

   ```
       XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
       doc.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

       foreach (XmlNode require_skill in doc.ChildNodes)
       {
           foreach (XmlNode skillIds in require_skill.ChildNodes)
           {
               builder.Append(skillIds.InnerText);
               builder.Append(" ");
           }
       }

       string attributeStr = builder.ToString().Substring(0, builder.Length - 1);

       string finalStr = "<require_skill skillIds=\"" + attributeStr + "\"\\>";
   ```
3. You can then write this string to a file using "System.IO.File.WriteAllText" as

   ```
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText("filename.xml", finalStr);
   ```

Hope this helps.